# Dynamic Web Programming

Tags: language-agnostic

Earlier today, I decided to start working on a small control panel for administration purposes. I was thinking of writing the script in PHP as I've used it in the past, but I wanted to check out ASP.NET aswell.

I started programming with JAVA in 2006, but i haven't really focused much on JAVA. Then i came across C#, I started focusing around May of this year, and have gotten incredibly familiar with C#. I know the basics of PHP, but i'm more familiar with C#, so ASP.NET using C# would allow me to understand the code easier.

The reason i want to use PHP though, is because the C# server i wrote uses MySQL, and PHP has built in functions for working with MySQL, but C# requires a connector (provided by MySQL).

I am also looking into programming as my career and have already - I mainly look into developing C# as the only operating system i use is windows.

Would anyone help point me in the right direction?
Thanks,
AJ Ravindiran.

Comment: Point you in what direction? You never actually asked a specific question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp+vs+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at programming as a career option then I suggest you learn about "programming". i.e. programming paradigms and concepts.  Programming languages are just tools.  You will want to be proficient in several.  Many languages borrow ideas from each other which makes picking up new languages easy.

e.g. C# has a similar syntax to Java which is also similar to C++ in syntax with some differences.  So learning any of these languages will enable you to switch to any of the others fairly easily.

If you want to be focused more on web development make sure you learn javascript as every browser uses that for dynamic content.  Also, it's helpful to know at least basic SQL and it sounds like you know that.  PHP is very widely used and supported.  C# too.  I'd learn a bit of both.  Focus on becoming a versatile developer.  Have an attitude of always wanting to learn.

Comment: The average website is written in 3 languages.  SQL at the backend, C#, PHP, perl or some other language in the middle section, and javascript on the browser end to privide dynamic content and a richer web experience.

Answer (score 1):

I started off with PHP then moved to .NET. I never regretted the move and I'm better off for it. .NET can do more, it's easier to use, and it has higher paying jobs. Moreover, you won't limit yourself to web programming if you start studying .NET.

You can download a free "light" version of visual studio from www.asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of preference. I use PHP but I use PDO (a database abstraction layer) for talking to MySQL because I feel that the native database function inside a language are bad design. When you use the native functions it's impossible to later change your database if you need to.

As far as a career in programming it's always helpful to know more than one language and more than one platform.

Again my opinion. If Windows and C# meet your goals then there is nothing wrong with using them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a good reason for not writing the application in each?  Putting aside that you'd scrap one, do you have a justification?  I ask because this seems like an excellent opportunity for you to explore both PHP and ASP.Net and see what pain points in each you discover.  Anyone could say that doing X in Y technology is easy and simple, but is it that way for you?  That's a question only you can answer?

Answer (score 0):

c# will [connect to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) just fine, if that's your main concern.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's time to checkout fresh ones: [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) programming language with [Lift](http://liftweb.com/) web framework?